# Solutions of a symmetrical system of $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've tried to solve the following system, but the process seems a bit awkward to me. Any hints?

1. $x+y+z=6$
2. $xyz=6$
3. $xy+yz+zx=11$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [relation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) between the coefficients of a polynomial equation of degree $n$ and its roots.

> It follows easily that $ x, y, z $ are the roots of the equation 
>  $$ p^3 - 6p^2 + 11p -6 = 0 \Leftrightarrow (p-1)(p-2)(p-3) = 0, $$ 
>  which are $ p = 1, 2, 3 $. The equations of the system are symmetrical in $ x, y, z $. Then, the six solutions of the system are the permutations of $ 1, 2, 3 $: *i.e.*, $$ (x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1). $$

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

With the given info, $x,y$ and $z$ are roots to the polynomial
$$
s^3-6s^2+11s-6=s^3-3s^2-3s^2+9s+2s-6\\
=(s-3)(s^2-3s+2)=(s-3)(s-1)(s-2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the roots of a cubic equation $t^3 + at^2 + bt + c=0$ is always $-a$.
The product of the roots is always $-c$. And the sum of products taken 2 at a time is $+b$.

Let $x, y, z$ be the three roots of a cubic equation.  Then from your givens, that cubic equation is
$$
t^3 -6t^2 +11t -6 =0
$$
Since the sum of the coefficients is zero, +1 will be a root.  Then you can factor out $(t-1)$ leaving
$$
(t-1)(t^2-5t+6)=0
$$
The quadratic is trivial to solve, with roots of 2 and 3.  So the answer you want is $(x,y,z) = (1,2,3)$ in any order.